# What jobs would be necessary on a colony world with no access to any other civilized planet? (Too far away/no FTL travel)

Tags: population, future

I need to know what jobs/roles a completely self sufficient colony world would need to get started and continue to function.

The colony would be made up of 200k-300k colonists. They would be organized into three different towns on the surface for various reasons.
The colony will not have access to any other human world because of extreme distance and a lack of fuel upon arrival.
Assume the world is habitable by the time they land. But there is no existing infrastructure. They would have a water source(rivers) and most vegetation is native. With temperatures similar to earth.

If they have governors, builders, engineers, farmers healthcare and emergency services are there essentials that I'm missing that could make my world more complete?

Comment: A quack... 2 in one! ;D

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Worldbuilding SE!  I think it would be helpful to know what the planet is like: is it essentially Earthlike?  Does it have a native biosphere, or would all plants and animals be imports?  Are there any special jobs that would be needed that would not be needed on Earth?  Separately, I'd say don't necessarily be so quick to import Earth's high degree of specialization to your colony.  With only 300k people, does it makes sense to have carpenters, masons, electricians, plumbers, and engineers all separate?  Could one job fill most of those roles on an as-needed basis?

Comment: Tinker, tailor, butcher, baker, candlestick maker, actor, barber, blacksmith, bodyguard, bricklayer, broker, cabinet maker, carpenter, charwoman, chemist, chimney sweep, cook, copywriter, cosmetician, dancer, drover, dustman, electronist, engineer, engraver, exterminator, florist, glazier, hairdresser, informer, lawyer, librarian, lifeguard, mechanic, milkmaid, model, money lender, news reporter, notary public, personal assistant, photographer, postman, printer, prostitute, salesperson, seamstress, shepherd, shoemaker, singer, spy, teamster, undertaker, waiter, wall painter, washerwoman, ...

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We solve worldbuilding problems, we don't compile arbitrarily long lists. Please check the [help] for more info

Comment: **Use elimination**

There are too requisite skills to mention even if you assume that each individual combines many skills. 

I suggest the alternative method of finding the ones who *aren't* necessary and then you need everyone else.

This has already been answered by Douglas Adams in Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy

> The Golgafrincham Ark Fleet Ship B was a starship designed to relocate
 the (largely redundant) useless part of the population from the planet of Golgafrincham.
 -  https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Golgafrincham

Answer (score 1):

**If you have the ability to go to another interstellar planet, you likely do not need most of the jobs you have listed**

The advantage you have is, being a interstellar colonist, you are already technologically advanced and well-educated.

So, more than likely, you would have the robots, computers and machines (and if not the expertise to build them) that would handle most [Primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_sector_of_the_economy) (Production) and [Secondary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_sector_of_the_economy) (Manufacturing) industries.

Even [Tertiary industries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy) can be automated by the time you arrive, so you may not require too much in the way of professional / legal or technical expertise.

In fact - one could argue that if machines and automation is largely available, all you need are cultural and political functions fulfilled by people, such as:

- Artists
- Architects
- Politicians
- Musicians
- Poets and Authors
- Entertainers

These professions are the considered the 'last' to be automated, as they are largely concerned with relationships, human nature and the inherent need for human expression.

BTW: You could go further and argue, if A.I. has accompanied your journey to another star and planet, *that even these may be redundant*.

Comment: I don't know... Shouldn't it be the case for us to already see the beginnings of this evolution towards a universal leisure society? And yet we don't. We have all the occupations which existed in ancient Rome and a hundred times more. For example, yes, our car factories are automated in a large degree; and yet, there are hundreds of occupations related to a car factory, from machinist to painter to receptionist to accountant to designer and so on.

Comment: Someone has to build the machines.

Comment: @CWallach - Machines build machines nowadays. Human factory workers are only used because they are cheaper in some cases - but this is not a sustainable reason. Eventually it would be cheaper to build all-machine manufacturing processes.